# R formula on a dataframe

Tags: r, plyr

I want to add the formulas I have used in a series of models to a data.frame

```
require(plyr)
require(nlme)
str(baseball)
ba <- baseball[1:100,]
m01 <- gls( g ~ ab+I(r^2)+cos(pi*h),data=ba,correlation = corARMA(p=1))
m02 <- gls( g ~ I(ab^3)+r+cos(pi*h)+sin(pi*h),data=ba,correlation = corARMA(p=1))
m03 <- gls( g ~ ab+r,data=ba,correlation = corARMA(p=1))
```

I have 3 models then I want two columns: the name of the model and the formula

```
mof <-ldply(ls(pattern=glob2rx("m0*")))

mof <-ddply(mof, .(V1),transform, form =formula(V1))
```

which gives

```
Error en as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class '"formula"' into a data.frame
```

I have tried a lot of different things but can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first colum is the name of the models that is ok,

```
mof <-ldply(ls(pattern=glob2rx("m0*")))
```

And the second column should be the formula of the models

```
names(mof)[1] <- "model"
mof$formula <- as.character(lapply(mof$model,formula))
```

and that works perfectly, after that I will add columns with corrected AIC and other things for model selection, but that is working fine.

Thanks to all commenters!

Answer (score 3):

When you are working with language elements some of the rules change. You apparently want a character column or two to label your results but what you have constructed in that first "mof" object is a character vector with just the names of the models, not the models themselves.

```
> str(mof)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: chr  "m01" "m02" "m03"
```

To retrieve the models from the workspace using character vectors you need to use `get`. They would then be available for further processing with the functions `formula` and `as.character`. You then will need to "go back" to character mode at the end, since objects of class-formula are not valid dataframe components. All in one nested call this would be:

```
> forms.mat <- sapply( lapply( lapply(mof$V1, get) , formula), as.character)
> forms.mat
     [,1]                        [,2]                                      [,3]    
[1,] "~"                         "~"                                       "~"     
[2,] "g"                         "g"                                       "g"     
[3,] "ab + I(r^2) + cos(pi * h)" "I(ab^3) + r + cos(pi * h) + sin(pi * h)" "ab + r"
```

You could rearrange (to get the tilde back in between the LHS and the RHS expressions and paste together (with collapse="") with:

```
> apply(forms.mat[ c(2,1,3),], 2, paste, collapse="")
[1] "g~ab + I(r^2) + cos(pi * h)"               "g~I(ab^3) + r + cos(pi * h) + sin(pi * h)"
[3] "g~ab + r"
```

---

You might have simplified this a bit by just working with a list:

```
> mof2 <- list(m01,m02,m03)  # Skipping the search of the workspace and reconstitution 
> lapply(mof2, formula)
[[1]]
g ~ ab + I(r^2) + cos(pi * h)
<environment: 0x2ef997c60>

[[2]]
g ~ I(ab^3) + r + cos(pi * h) + sin(pi * h)
<environment: 0x19fef52d0>

[[3]]
g ~ ab + r
<environment: 0x19fef68d8>

> sapply( lapply(mof2, formula), as.character )
     [,1]                        [,2]                                      [,3]    
[1,] "~"                         "~"                                       "~"     
[2,] "g"                         "g"                                       "g"     
[3,] "ab + I(r^2) + cos(pi * h)" "I(ab^3) + r + cos(pi * h) + sin(pi * h)" "ab + r"
```

Comment: also u can get all the formulas applying m01$call[2], m02$call[2] ... I know this is simple and if u will have more than few calls it would be annoying to do it - but I think it's more informative - as it's for me; but agree that @DWin answer is more automatic

Comment: Those are still language objects and as such will create problem if attempts are made to insert  into dataframes.